# I keep getting a ']' expected error [Java]

Tags: java, arrays

**For some reason eclipse keeps giving me a ']' error at npcname_m[0]="steve";**

```
    String npcname_m[]=new String[10];
    npcname_m[0]="Steve";
    npcname_m[1]="John";
    npcname_m[2]="Mark";
    npcname_m[3]="Andrew";
    npcname_m[4]="Matthew";
    npcname_m[5]="Luke";
    npcname_m[6]="Miguel";
    npcname_m[7]="Michael";
    npcname_m[8]="Josh";
    npcname_m[9]="Alex";
```

*Entire Code*

```
public class npc
{
    //NPC Types; Speci
    public enum npctype{villager, mob, special, hostile, passive, placeholder}
    npctype npc_type =npctype.placeholder;
    String npcname_m[]=new String[10];
    npcname_m[0]="Steve";
    npcname_m[1]="John";
    npcname_m[2]="Mark";
    npcname_m[3]="Andrew";
    npcname_m[4]="Matthew";
    npcname_m[5]="Luke";
    npcname_m[6]="Miguel";
    npcname_m[7]="Michael";
    npcname_m[8]="Josh";
    npcname_m[9]="Alex";

    String[] npcname_f = new String[10];
    npcname_f[0]="Mariah";
    npcname_f[1]="Joyce";
    npcname_f[2]="Kaede Akamatsu";
    npcname_f[3]="Iruma Miu";
    npcname_f[4]="Maki";
    npcname_f[5]="Hannah";
    npcname_f[6]="Angie";
    npcname_f[7]="Grace";
    npcname_f[8]="Melissa";
    npcname_f[9]="Alex";

    public enum npcclass{weak, strong, rare}
    String name = "Placeholder to avoid problems with garbage collector";
    int healthpoints =100;
    int moneyreward =100;
    int attackpower=100;
    Boolean male = true;

    //code to attack player if player starts dsplaying aggressive behaviour torward friendly NPC's
    //Placeholder code
    public void AttackHostilePlayer(){
    return;
    }

    public void TransformHostileVillager(){
        healthpoints= healthpoints + 50;
        attackpower=attackpower + 50;
        System.out.println(npc_type);
        return;
    }

    //Generates an npc (Add randomisation later)
    public void generatenpc(){
        male = true;
        name= "Steve";
        npc_type=npctype.villager;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `String[] npcname_m = new String[10];`

Comment: Thanks but it still gives me the same error

Comment: How did you use it, maybe the adding data part is out of the method.

Comment: Try commenting all except first line. Maybe you have an invisible character in your code.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Copy/pasted code, and it compiles fine. I agree with @MasterDJon: You likely have invisible characters. Try deleting the code and copy/paste from here.

Comment: I copy & pasted it like you said for some reason it keeps resulting in the error

Comment: What lines of code do you have before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't write code outside a class' method except for variable definition in Java.

```
public class npc
{   
    String[] npcname_m = new String[10];

    // INVALID CODE ! npcname_m[0]="Steve";

    public npc() {
        npcname_m[0]="Steve";
    }

}
```

Comment: They can do this instead: `String[] npcname_m = {"Steve", "John", "Mark",...,"Josh", "Alex"};`

Comment: @walen I know, but the answer here is to pin point the error reusing the same code. Better to learn with small steps.

Comment: For the poster (OP), just remembering you that if an answer fits your needs, you shall accept it. Mine or who's ever answer.

Answer (score -2):

Use `String[] npcname_m=new String[10];` instead.

Comment: This _definitely_ will result in syntax error.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to delete the second []

Comment: Did you see my comment above?  It didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Not until now. Interesting, I tried in my IDE and this works fine.

Comment: You tried in _your_ IDE, but the OP has some other issue.